# [SCHEME][GIMP] How create a new directory / folder?

Tags: scheme, directory, gimp, script-fu

I write a script-fu into Gimp whith scheme langage and i am looking for a method that would allow me to create a new folders without going through the "SF-DIRNAME" command.

Advance thanks.

Comment: I strongly suggest making scripts in python rather than in script-fu, and douby so for more sophisticated scripts. Dealgn with directories, fiels and so is a no brainer in Python. I don't know if tiny-scheme even has a way to deal with directories at all.